# Fetch random order of query in Firebase and Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, sorting, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

What is the best way to randomly sort a list of objects after you have fetched all the data? I've only been able to fetch the data, but don't know how to randomly sort it.

Firebase structure:
questions --> id: 1

Function to fetch all objects:

```
func fetchQuestions(completion: @escaping ([UserModel])->()) {
        
    let postRef = self.databaseRef.child("questions")
        postRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (poster) in
        
            var resultsArray = [UserModel]()
            for post in poster.children {
            
                let post = UserModel(snapshot: post as? DataSnapshot)
               
                resultsArray.append(post)
                    
        }
        
        completion(resultsArray)
        
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "I get a syntax error" What is the error and what line/statement is it on?

Comment: I get it on this line: resultsArray.append(UserModel(id: id[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(poster.count)))]). Error is Cannot find id in scope.

Comment: It looks like there is no array called `id` in this: `id[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(poster.count)))]`.

Comment: Any suggestions on how else to sort queries randomly? Not sure if there has been questions around this before but I searched and couldn't find any

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+random? But you'll have to do it for Flutter. But what you have here is a syntax error. What do you think `id` is in the snippet of you code that I mentioned above? Because according to the compiler it doesn't exist, so you'll need to tell us what you expect that single statement to do.